# Cannot cannot do pip install --no-deps in editable mode

Tags: pip

How do I install a package with pip in [editable mode](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) and also [not install its dependencies](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-deps)?

I tried both `--no-deps` and `--no-dependencies`:

```
$ pip install -e --no-deps .
ERROR: --no-deps is not a valid editable requirement. It should 
either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with svn+, 
git+, hg+, or bzr+).

$ pip install -e --no-dependencies .
ERROR: --no-dependencies is not a valid editable requirement. It should 
either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with svn+, 
git+, hg+, or bzr+).
```

but I always get an error.

Leaving out `-e` or `--no-deps` works:

```
$ pip install -e .
$ pip install --no-deps .
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pip` is a little quirky here. You have to have the `--no-deps` option before the `-e` option:

```
pip install --no-deps -e .
```

The docs [technically list `-e` separately from the "options"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#usage).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! This feels like a bug to me. Did you open an issue in pip?